# How to avoid ambiguous overloads on inherited function calls using enable_if or concepts?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I try to implement a property storage using a base class that provides get() and set() functions. The base class is a template and all properties are unique types. This works well as long the property storage is used only once in the inheritance structure. [See here](https://github.com/majorkingleo/STM32F401RE_FlashTest/blob/stack_overflow_question_example/Drivers/stm32_internal_flash/Inc/MemoryInterface.h)

If the set() function is not unique anymore I get the compiler error: set() is ambiguous.

Since the types are unique it would be possible to deactivate the set() function if it is not valid for the template.

Here is my minimal example code ([online compiler here](https://godbolt.org/z/ha3f9a89P)):

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Type>
struct Base
{
    Type t;

    template <typename T>
    requires( std::is_same_v<Type,T> )
    void set( T t_ ) {
        t = t_;
    }
};


struct A : public Base<bool>
{

};

struct B : public A, public Base<int>
{

};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.set(true);

    B b;
    b.set(1); // request for member 'set' is ambiguous
    b.set(false); // should be automatically deligated to A::set()
}
```

The complete error message from g++-13 is:

```
main.cc: In function 'int main()':
main.cc:38:11: error: request for member 'set' is ambiguous
   38 |         b.set(1);
      |           ^~~
main.cc:16:14: note: candidates are: 'template<class T>  requires  is_same_v<Type, T> void Base<Type>::set(T) [with Type = int]'
   16 |         void set( T t_ ) {
      |              ^~~
main.cc:16:14: note:                 'template<class T>  requires  is_same_v<Type, T> void Base<Type>::set(T) [with Type = bool]'
```

Is it possible to solve this somehow?

Comment: `struct A : public Base<bool>{ using Base<bool>::set; };` and `struct B : public Base<int>{ using Base<int>::set; };`

Comment: Yes this solves the problem for my example code, but I also want to type:
`b.set(false)`
So in this case base of A should be called.

Comment: Then write `using Base<int>::set; using A::set;`. Did you read the duplicates?